# ChaTGPT to discord not responding to prompts

Tags: node.js, discord, openai-api

I have set up a bot on discord and I am trying to use this code make it work. the code runs and does not give any error. the bot goes online but when I ask question there is no reply.... can you help me solve it? tokens are stored correctly on .env

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js'); 
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
const client = new Client({ intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
]});

const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: process.env.OPENAI_ORG,
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  openai.promise({
    prompt: message.content,
    model: "text-davinci-002",
    temperature: 0.7,
    max_tokens: 1024,
    n: 1,
    stop: "",
    engine: "davinci",
  })
    .then((result) => {
      message.reply(result.choices[0].text);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Does ChaTGPT refuse to "chat' with robots?

Comment: ChatGPT has no API yet. You're talking to an older model, davinci.